# Integration by parts. Wolfram agrees with my answer, book doesn't.

Tags: integration, area

The question is:

find the integral using integration by parts

$\int ln(2x+1) dx $

I set $ f = 2x+1 $, $(1/2)df = dx$

$(1/2) \int ln(f)df $

$ u= ln(f), du = (1/f), dv = df, v = f $

$fln(f) - \int(1) $

$(1/2)(fln(f) - f ) $

$(1/2)(  (2x+1)ln(2x+1)  - (2x+1)  ) $

Wolfram agrees with my answer, :

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+ln(2x%2B1)

But my book gives the answer of:

$(1/2)(2x+1)ln(2x+1) -x + c$

does anyone know where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct solutions. Note that your solution expands to 
$$\frac{1}{2}(2x+1)\ln(2x+1)  - \frac{1}{2}(2x+1)+C$$
Which further expands to
$$\frac{1}{2}(2x+1)\ln(2x+1)  - x -\frac{1}{2}+C$$
Your book is just wrapping up the $\frac{-1}{2}$ into the constant. The main problem here is just that you forgot to include a constant of integration in your answer. Other than that, what you wrote is fine.